# Significance of @autoreleasepool in iOS 6

Tags: nsautoreleasepool

Older version of XCode, if you remove autorelease pool code in main.m the application used to crash. But now even if I dont have any statement such as @autoreleasepool in main.m then also the app works fine. What has changed? I tried with ARC and without ARC both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Objective-C runtime installs an "autorelease pool of last resort" for you. It's best not to rely on it.

Comment: Thanks Catfish_Man, it makes sense but is it something added recently?

Comment: I suspect it was probably added when autorelease pools moved from Foundation/CoreFoundation to libobjc (which was the same release ARC was introduced)